# Compare time From DateTimeField-Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

I have one table with field "CreatedTime" as datetime fileld(eg:2012-09-18 13:01:33). I want to fetch all the rows in that table with CreatedTime as "AM"(ie Before 12). How can I write a query for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT * FROM table_name where date_format(CreatedTime,'%p') = 'AM'

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE hour(CreatedTime) < 12
```